# Mask image is not visible in ::before of an element in Firefox browser

Tags: css, firefox, mask

Mask image is not working in ::before selector in firefox and working properly in chrome.
Is there any work around to make it visible? I don't want to replace everything with background image.

```
.toolbar-icon-shortcut::before {
  -webkit-mask-image: url('./test/sprite.svg#shortcut-view');
  mask-image: url('./test/sprite.svg#shortcut-view');
  background-color: #000;
  -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-mask-position: center center;
  mask-position: center center;
}
```

Comment: check your browser console, you have probably a CORS error

Comment: Yes getting the error CORS error for the images. How can I fix it? Not getting the error in chrome.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394277/8620333